# Como concatenar propriedades de uma única List<> com LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Preciso concatenar duas propriedades de cada item da minha lista, no exemplo abaixo ele funciona mas gostaria de saber como posso fazer a mesma coisa usando LINQ no lugar do `foreach`?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Pessoas> lstPessoas = new List<Pessoas>();
        Pessoas pessoa = null;

        pessoa = new Pessoas();
        pessoa.Id = 1;
        pessoa.Nome = "Mauricio";
        lstPessoas.Add(pessoa);

        pessoa = new Pessoas();
        pessoa.Id = 2;
        pessoa.Nome = "João";
        lstPessoas.Add(pessoa);

        pessoa = new Pessoas();
        pessoa.Id = 3;
        pessoa.Nome = "Maria";
        lstPessoas.Add(pessoa);

        foreach (Pessoas item in lstPessoas)
        {
            item.Nome = item.Id + " - " + item.Nome;
        }
    }
}

public class Pessoas
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Eu pensei que fosse linq-to-sql ainda sou novo no assunto. Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vê alguma razão para fazer isso? Isto gera efeito colateral, ou seja, algum dado é modificado, então o LINQ não é adequado. O Q aí é de *query*, ou seja, de consulta. Quando você quer fazer mais que uma consulta o melhor é usar o comando `for each` mesmo. O LINQ não deve ser usado quando ele não traz benefícios claros. Se vai insistir pode usar o método [`ForEach()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_ForEach_System_Action__0__):

```
lstPessoas.ForEach(item => item.Nome = item.Id + " - " + item.Nome);
```

Código:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lstPessoas = new List<Pessoas>();

        var pessoa = new Pessoas {
            Id = 1,
            Nome = "Mauricio" };
        lstPessoas.Add(pessoa);

        pessoa = new Pessoas {
            Id = 2,
            Nome = "João" };
        lstPessoas.Add(pessoa);

        pessoa = new Pessoas {
            Id = 3,
            Nome = "Maria" };
        lstPessoas.Add(pessoa);

        lstPessoas.ForEach(item => item.Nome = item.Id + " - " + item.Nome);
        foreach (var item in lstPessoas) {
            WriteLine(item.Nome);
        }
    }
}

public class Pessoas {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/s866g1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oLHOJr). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/ForEach.cs). Curiosamente eu fiz um `for each` para mostrar o resultado e ali o LINQ até faria mais sentido.

Comment: Cara era exatamente isso que eu queria, esse trecho de código que você colou é linq certo? Na minha visão dessa forma que vc apresentou em termos de performance parece ser mais rápido e deixa o código mais limpo. Muito Obrigado abraço.

Comment: Sim, é LINQ. Isto é mais lento que o uso do comando. Há controvérsias se o código fica mais limpo. Ele fica ligeiramente menor. Mas é fácil cair em armadilhas quando há efeito colateral usando desta forma. Claro que em um exemplo simples não terá problemas. Tem casos que sequer funciona.

Comment: Obrigado eu não sabia:).